# Translate isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively to my Spock Test

Tags: java, testing, junit, assert, spock

I am translating all my Junit Tests into Spock Tests and I don't want to use any "Assert methods". Therefore I have to translate the method *isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively* into my Groovy class. I am not sure, if I understood the function of the method correctly.

`assertThat(validationMessage).isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(provider.createValidationMessageDto());`

In this case *validationMessage* is a DTO-Object and *provider.createValidationMessageDto* returns the same kind of DTO-Object. Does there already exist any similar method or do I have to code a new own method, which checks *validationMessage*? And if so, what should the method do?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the validation message DTO doesn't provide a proper equals methods, then sticking with `isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively` might be your best solution.
While Spock has great implicit assertion, something like reflective field-by-field compare isn't directly supported.

You could use Spock's support for Hamcrest and it's [samePropertyValuesAs](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/2.1/org/hamcrest/beans/SamePropertyValuesAs.html) to write:

```
import static org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs.samePropertyValuesAs
import static spock.util.matcher.HamcrestSupport.that
// ...
expect:
that validationMessage, samePropertyValuesAs(provider.createValidationMessageDto()
```

However, that does not do recursive comparison, for that you could use https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest

Comment: Shazamcrest looks interesting. I never used it or AssertJ before. I think AssertJ is where `isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively()` comes from. So how would you explain your choice in this case, one external library vs. another one? Is it Spock's Hamcrest support only, making you select Shazamcrest? Are there other reasons?

Comment: @kriegaex I would go with whatever is known in the team and does the job. Shazamcrest's last release was in 2015, but that doesn't mean it is bad, sometimes a small library is just doing what it should and doesn't need more development. However, I didn't look to deeply into, just found it while searching if the hamcrest one could do deep comparison. Also, I didn't make a choice here, I just presented an alternative, the AssertJ example was provided by OP already.